# NativeScript (Telerik) and Serial Port on Android

Tags: android, node.js, telerik, serial-port, nativescript

I need to utilize both a barcode scanner and a USB port on something handheld. I figure a small Android Tablet is my best option.

I've spent some time researching and I cannot find anyone who has implemented a NativeScript App w/ Serial Port communication on Android.

I am concerned this means it is not possible, or prohibited for some reason.

I have the Serial Communication functional right now using Nodejs and the serialport module via NPM.

Does anyone know if this module will work in a NativeScript app?

I am going to attempt to make this work over the weekend, but before I waste a lot of time I figured I would ask in case this is simply not possible -- I've chased simple bugs for days so I could waste a long time on something that's not possible. :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you can do with a pure Java-only app (or Swift/Object C for iOS)  you can do with NativeScript as you can access all the underlining APIs. This is one of (if not *the*) key differences between NativeScript and other technologies. See [the NativeScript docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/marshalling/js-to-java.html).

Most probably, you'll want to use some third party code to communicate with the serial device (such as [usb-serial-for-android](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android)). Here's a [great blog post on how to use third party code](http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=167) in your NativeScript app.

Comment: Thanks, Emil. I thought that was what I was reading, but I wasn't certain. 

Do you happen to know if the NPM module [serialport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) will work? 

I originally started this project to be used on a Microsoft Surface tablet, so I've got this module functional in an Electron (Atom) App --- but the Microsoft hardware is so expensive and I found NativeScript so I decided to possibly pivot to an Android solution.

Comment: This [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/nativescript/serial$20port/nativescript/YKVLXFWFN0M/iqergUY2BgAJ) could be useful.

Comment: Emil, could you find a solution for this?